# APEX 5: Adding subtotals in IR Pivot

Tags: pivot-table, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I've created a pivot table using the Interactive Report Feature. The only total option it gives me is a grand total for each column, but I also want to include sub totals. For eg, in the below screenshot, I would like to see subtotals by region per week, apart from the grand totals per week. Is it possible?

[image: Pivot table example]

Answer (score 2):

You can get subtotals if the report has a Control Break, but not on pivoted columns. The way I'd approach this is to add an additional column "week" to the report query which truncates the date to the nearest week (e.g. `trunc(mydatecolumn,'W')`; put a Control Break on that (as well as region).